# URL/ Path in address bar

Tags: url, path, address-bar

I have seen my websites only shows path as below when you navigate to different webpage or items in that website while when i created the website i have to create a webpage for everything & it do show the path with file name like .php while other websites only show a path even though it navigate to new page.

Comment: 1. What is the question? 2. What is the problem? 3. What have you tried? (can and does include google search) 4. Where have you failed?

Comment: “only shows paths as below” — have you included the ”below” section?

Comment: @Shingetsu  . Here is what I am talking about. See the webpage http://www.stockashop.co.uk/. Now when you click any of menu & sub-menu item it will open a new page but the Url remains "http://www.stockashop.co.uk/pages/collarways-case-study/6651"  no .php or html or any other extension for page.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as URL routing. The developer has configured the webserver (or web application) to map specific URL paths to individual webserver pages (.php, .aspx, .mvc, or whatever). There are different ways of achieving this, depending on the webserver platform technology, but it is generally achieved by configuring a url route map of some kind. There are several advantages to organising a website url's in this way but mainly it makes URL's more consistent and easier to understand for users, and hides the details of the website's underlying implementation.